# Angular reactive form, default value of input

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

```
ngOnInit() { 
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({ 
    Email: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    Password: [{ value: 12345678, disabled: true }, [Validators.required, 
    Validators.minLength(8)]],              
});
```

Hello, Is there a way to set a password value in my form by calling a function?

For example if I have a

```
getPassword(): number {
    return 12345678;
}
```

How can i call it in my form builder instead of "value: ...", because I was hoping to create a function that will give me a random number each time and set it to disabled so I could send email and random password through form...

Comment: `Password: [{ value: getPassword() ....` doesn't work?

Comment: It works! Thanks, actually, this.getPassword() lol

Comment: Anyone has some advice, how to show password as ******* ?

Comment: @codemonkey00016 That is a different question. Only one topic per question, please.

Comment: hey, sorry :)))

Answer (score 0):

As you've seen above, the anwser goes like this...

```
   ngOnInit() { 

    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({ 
    Email: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    Password: [{ value: this.getPassword(), disabled: true }, 
    [Validators.required, 
    Validators.minLength(8)]],

    });
```

}

And function which gives back 8 random characters...

```
  getPassword(): any {
   return Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 8);

  }
```